# How to load data from a specific column in datatable

Tags: winforms, datatable, epplus

I have a datatable that I created programmatically (no connection used etc) and in my datatable I have 2 columns. I would only like to export the value from 2nd column to excel. For my code below, it export the data from both columns inside excel. How do I write for exporting only a specific column?

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            string filepath = "C:\\Trial.xlsx";
            ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("test");
            ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt1, false);
            pck.SaveAs(new FileInfo(filepath));
        }
        this.Close();
    }
```

Comment: you can iterate through your dt1, and set each cell (dont forget to increment row) separetly. you can access a cell also by a row/col pair. (somehting like: ws.Cells[row, column].Value = your value from your table....)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy your `DataTable` into temporary table and remove columns, you don't want and then export to excel.

Example:

```
DataTable tempDataTable;
tempDataTable = table.Copy();
tempDataTable.Columns.Remove("NameOfColumnYouDontWant");
```

In your code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            string filepath = "C:\\Trial.xlsx";
            ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("test");
            DataTable tempDataTable;
            tempDataTable = dt1.Copy();
            tempDataTable.Columns.Remove("NameOfColumnYouDontWant");
            # Remove all columns you don't need
            ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(tempDataTable, false);
            pck.SaveAs(new FileInfo(filepath));
        }
        this.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Deleted my previous comment. As my 'bool' column have 3 rows so I did a `for (int i = 1; i <=3; i++)` then I copied your code. This will then show all the data in my column. Thanks for your time.